# What would cause spurious relationship when using logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, scikit-learn, regularization

I generated random values from a normal distribution(using numpy.random.normal) and threw them into a logistic regression model as X variables(~300 of them). Y is binary( around 51% is 1 ) and is from an actual dataset that I'm working on.

I used sklearn LogisticRegression with l1 penalty and did cross validation on the hyperparameter C using AUC as evaluation metric. What bothers me is the C value that yields the highest AUC wouldn't give me all zero coefficients. Since Xs are not relevant at all, wouldn't a constant model work the best? If that's true, the C selected should be small enough to force all coefficients to zero.

I tried a few runs with different seeds and the highest AUCs were significantly higher than 0.5. And my question is how do I tell if it's a spurious relationship or a truly legitimate model.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a very long history, and a multitude of posts on this site about overfitting and multiple comparison problems.  It would be good to survey these areas first.

Answer (score 0):

Update on this in case anyone has the same question. The sample size was not big enough. After I increased the sample size, hyperparameter C selected would always be small enough to keep the coefficients at 0.